# Avoid Android Studio JUnit run configurations litter

Tags: android-studio, junit

In Android Studio (3.0.1), I write a JUnit test class or method and then click the arrow icon in the gutter to the left and run the test. It appears that this creates a new Run Configuration.

In the Run/Debug Configuration dropdown, I switch back to the JUnit configuration I use for the entire module. I no longer need the Run Configuration created a moment ago -- and if I wanted to rerun the test, I can just use the gutter icon.

If I run several tests in a row, they will reappear in the dropdown when I restart Android Studio. But they're all unusable, with red X's. Attempting to run fails with "Unknown run configuration type JUnit".

- Does this happen to others, or is my project or IDE misconfigured?
- Is there a way to make these temporary configurations go away automatically?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I've been having this issue too, and also noticed that my test code is not recompiled.

Comment: No, I just put up with it, unfortunately. The test code not being re-compiled sounds like a different issue (that I believe is solvable).

Comment: Are you by chance using Kotlin? I only encounter this problem with tests written in Kotlin.